# Connecting two odoo instances on the same machine

Tags: database, connection, odoo, multiple-instances, odoo-12

On my windows machine, I created two odoo instances each one is running on a different port and using different databases, which means that the two are independent from each other.

My question is : I need to access create a connection between the instances using a user readOnly login, so **I can read second instance database tables from the first instance.**

I found some forum answers talking about LDP, but I am still confused of how I can do it on my local machine.

Any help please. Thanks a lot in adavance.

Answer (score 0):

About this i think you need to give the second odoo instance the same database user in your configuration odoo file db_user= "YOUR ROLE"
I have just try it and it's working for me just for the second one you need to create read only user 
Note : if you are using a differente machine with two different ip address you'll need to configure postgres conf file to allow another ip address's to access to your postgres server 
Hope this will help